# Possible to minimise single-page attachments in Mail?

Tags: iphone, attachment, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have an iOS app which uses the locally-created Mail.app account to send emails with, and I am attaching a few PDF documents.

I have found that if the document is one-page long, when I call `[myMailComposer addAttachmentData:data mimeType:theMimeType fileName: fileName];` then the whole document is literally inserted into the mail, but if the document is >1 page then a thumbnail is created.

Is there a way of forcing thumbnail creation or elegantly hiding the document from view, or will the average iOS user know to tap and hold down on the 1-page document to launch 'quick look'? (this only occurs on an iPad - always thumbnails on an iPhone)

Thanks in advance for any advice.